# BLE onConnectionStateChange callback get STATE_DISCONNECTED after few attempts

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, altbeacon, gatt

**My Problem**

After few attempt the GATT service is getting disconnected i don't know the reason.I found that the **onConnectionStateChange** i got the status as **62** and **133**.But i don't know the exact reason or solution to solve the problem.

**Connection Code:**

```
 public boolean connectDevice(final BluetoothDevice device) {

    try {
        broadcastUpdate(MyUtils.ACTION_GATT_REQUEST,"Before connect called " + mContext);
        if (mContext != null) {

            mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(mContext, false,
                    mGattCallback);

            setmBluetoothGatt(mBluetoothGatt);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}
```

**CallBack**

```
 @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status,
                                        int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);

        String intentAction;
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionStateChange: status=>"+status+" newState=>"+newState);
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {


        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {

         }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

62 = 0x3E means "The Connection Failed to be Established error code indicates that the LL initiated a connection but the connection has failed to be established."

This means that the master tried to send 6 packets to the device but it never responded to any of them. There is probably nothing wrong with your Android code. You should instead check radio interference, clock drifts etc. You can use a BLE air sniffer to see what really happens.